# Ubuntu 17.04 not starting

Tags: boot, ubuntu-gnome

I've tried the recovery mode still not working. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong in that photo.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but It was ALWAYS something I have done in BIOS setting when Installing Ubuntu in the first place.You have probably changed the order of booting (To USB or something) and now it is trying to boot from USB, or something similar.

Go in your BIOS and see under BOOT options. Do not feel afraid to change something, as you will always be able to get there again to try another option.

Try to change a few setting and see where it will get you. (I have done this 100 times) Never caused any problems, only solved them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. Actually, Gnome Wayland wasn't responding. So, I looked out of the Gnome using tty1 and then restarted my PC. After that it booted well.